# Div only scrollable when an element is selected in the debug panel

Tags: html, css

I've come across a **really** strange issue. I've got a list of items in a ul > li, in a horizontally scrollable div, but I can only scroll the div on my phone (running Android L dev preview when I open up the debug panel and click on an element, doesn't matter what element it is. It works fine on my desktop PC, but this is for the mobile site.

I can't seem to reproduce the error in jsfiddle, but here's the CSS and HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/ya58twmj/1

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right hidden-lg hidden-md"></i>  <a href="#opening_times">Opening Times</a>

        </li>
        <li> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right hidden-lg hidden-md"></i>  <a href="#activities">Activities</a>

        </li>
        <li> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right hidden-lg hidden-md"></i>  <a href="#timetable">Timetable</a>

        </li>
        <li> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right hidden-lg hidden-md"></i>  <a href="#map_directions">Map/Directions</a>

        </li>
        <li> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right hidden-lg hidden-md"></i>  <a href="#events">Events</a>

        </li>
        <li> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right hidden-lg hidden-md"></i>  <a href="/venues">View other venues</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**
Ignore some of the duped properties, this was copied out of the computed css tab.

```
.wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family:'Noto Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 52px;
    line-height: 20px;
    min-height: 1px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 360px;
}

ul {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: block;
    font-family:'Noto Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    line-height: 20px;
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:'Noto Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Does anyone know what on earth is going on here?

Comment: You cannot scroll on your mobile? sorry did not get the issue.

Comment: Ok, so I have the same issue with the latest stable release of Chrome for mobile running on Kit Kat. Interestingly, there is no problem with the latest Chrome mobile Beta.

Comment: It is bizarre how it scrolls fine when inspected with Dev Tools.

Comment: See my answer for the problem, but I still don't know why it worked with the dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That pesky Z-Index...

There was a hidden menu effectively blocking my from actually clicking on that div to scroll.

Although I've no idea why it worked with dev tools.

This is essentially what I had. http://jsfiddle.net/ya58twmj/3/

```
<div id="hidden"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right hidden-lg hidden-md"></i>  <a href="#opening_times">Opening Times</a>

        </li>
        <li> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right hidden-lg hidden-md"></i>  <a href="#activities">Activities</a>

        </li>
        <li> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right hidden-lg hidden-md"></i>  <a href="#timetable">Timetable</a>

        </li>
        <li> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right hidden-lg hidden-md"></i>  <a href="#map_directions">Map/Directions</a>

        </li>
        <li> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right hidden-lg hidden-md"></i>  <a href="#events">Events</a>

        </li>
        <li> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right hidden-lg hidden-md"></i>  <a href="/venues">View other venues</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
#hidden {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:2;
}
.wrapper {
    z-index:1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family:'Noto Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 52px;
    line-height: 20px;
    min-height: 1px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 360px;
}
ul {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: block;
    font-family:'Noto Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    line-height: 20px;
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:'Noto Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```